# alert box shows up N times after clicking N times on submit button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, alert

Given this function:

```
function validate() {
   var elements = ["firstname", "lastname", "password", "favfood", "favsport"];

   document.getElementById('register').noValidate = true;
   document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
         if(document.getElementById(elements[i]).hasAttribute("required")) {
            if(!document.getElementById(elements[i]).checkValidity()) {
               event.preventDefault();
               alert('Please, fill in every required field of the form.');
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }, false);
}
```

And this form:

```
<form name="register" id="register" method="POST" action="this-file.php">
   [HTML ELEMENTS TO VALIDATE]
   <input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

When I press `Register` the first time (without filling in anything), the alert box shows up just once; if I press `Register` again, the alert box shows up twice and so on. What's going on?

I'm using a custom JavaScript function to validate my form because the `required` attribute does not work on Safari.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: you can disable the button once its clicked for the first time

Comment: I can't. The goal is to show an alert message if `required` elements are not set. If I disable the submit button after one click, the user wouldn't be able to click it anymore unless he/she reloads the page, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite straightforward, you are adding **submit** event listener each time whenever your hit submit button i.e. through `validate` function. There are two ways to handle this either register it only once or remove the added listener first and than add it.

**First Way**

```
function validate() {
   var elements = ["firstname", "lastname", "password", "favfood", "favsport"];

   document.getElementById('register').noValidate = true;
   document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
         if(document.getElementById(elements[i]).hasAttribute("required")) {
            if(!document.getElementById(elements[i]).checkValidity()) {
               event.preventDefault();
               alert('Please, fill in every required field of the form.');
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }, false);
}

validate(); // call this function directly and remove it from your submit button
```

**Second Way**

```
function validateCallback(event) {
    var elements = ["firstname", "lastname", "password", "favfood", "favsport"];

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     if(document.getElementById(elements[i]).hasAttribute("required")) {
        if(!document.getElementById(elements[i]).checkValidity()) {
           event.preventDefault();
           alert('Please, fill in every required field of the form.');
           break;
        }
     }
  }
}

function validate() {
   document.getElementById('register').noValidate = true;
   document.getElementById('register').removeEventListener('submit', validateCallback, false);
   document.getElementById('register').addEventListener('submit', validateCallback, false);
}
```

and use it same as you are using currently.

Comment: EDIT: I'm an idiot. I didn't copy your examples properly. Everything works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting more and more alerts because inside your `validate` method, you're adding a new event listener to the submit button each time.